# angularjs broadcast never received

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-broadcast

I have two injectors, the event from one scope never reaches the other scope even though they are the same scope supposedly...

http://jsfiddle.net/rkLzww3t/

```
angular.injector(['ng']).invoke(['$rootScope', function($root) {
    alert('will try to be usefull');
    $root.$on('bevent123', function() {
      alert('useful bevent123 never happens');
    });
}]);

angular.injector(['ng']).invoke(['$rootScope', function($root) {
    $root.$on('bevent123', function() {
      alert('bevent123 done from local injector, but we were not usefull');
    });
    console.log("about to $root.$broadcast('bevent123')");
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $root.$broadcast('bevent123');
    },1000);
}]);
```

## UPDATE

My main objective is in knowing when google maps has loaded and initialized...

```
var app = angular.module('module_name');

function googleCallback() {
  //run does not do anything if all modules are already loaded and initialized
  //angular.module('module_name').run(['$rootScope', function($root) {
  angular.injector(['ng']).invoke(['$rootScope', function($root) {
    console.log("about to $root.$broadcast('googleLoaded')");
    $root.googleLoaded = true;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $root.$broadcast('googleLoaded');
      //$root.$emit('googleLoaded');
    },1000);
  }]);
}

app.run(['$rootScope',function($root) {
  var element = document.createElement("script");
  element.type = 'text/javascript';
  element.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places&callback=googleCallback";
  element.async = true;
  var domElement = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  domElement.appendChild(element);
}]);

app.controller('Controller', ['$scope','$rootScope', function ($scope, $root) {
  function initMaps() {
    console.log("initMaps()");
  }
  $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    console.log('$viewContentLoaded');
    if (!$root.googleLoaded) {
      console.log("waiting for googleLoaded");
      $scope.$on("googleLoaded", function() {
        console.log("about to init");
        initMaps();
      });
    } else {
      initMaps();
    }
  });
}]);//end of app.controller('Controller'...
```

everything works perfect until `"about to init"` never gets logged to the console and the api doesn't get setup

Comment: Try `$root.$emit('bevent123');` in your timeout.

Comment: There is no relation between from injector to controller,so rootScope.emit or broadcast won't work on scope.on.,try using $rootScope.$on()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two scopes are not the same.

> I have to broadcast on $rootScope from a global function

You can get the injector of the application via a DOM element. E.g.:

```
angular.element(document.body).injector()
```

Instead of `invoke` you could call `get` to get an angular service and use that. Definitely better then a "raw" global function.

Answer (score 0):

Inject ng only once and invoke on that same instance. It will work now.

```
var app = angular.injector(['ng'])

app.invoke(['$rootScope', function($root) {
    alert('will try to be usefull');
    $root.$on('bevent123', function() {
      alert('useful bevent123 never happens');
    });   }])

app.invoke(['$rootScope', function($root) {
    $root.$on('bevent123', function() {
      alert('bevent123 done from local injector, but we were not usefull');
    });
    console.log("about to $root.$broadcast('bevent123')");
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $root.$broadcast('bevent123');
    },1000);

}]);
```

Comment: yes,it will invoked only once when the your app is inititiliazed for the first time,because module.run is just called after the module.config when all the services and dependencies are injected and taken care of.Why not use it in controller?

Comment: Even though it's broadcast on rootScope, it's only broadcast to rootScope for its individual object. angular.injector(['ng']) creates a new object each time called. `var A=angular.injector(['ng'])`, `var B=angular.injector(['ng'])`, A !== B. Invoking the invoke method only adds that function to one and not the other. You should create a module and pass that module reference around.